# How to make dictionary NSDictionary be thread safe for reading, inserting?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8

At every start of application I have to fetch couple .plists from server and later some of them I am using in code ( depends on user's choice ). To avoid loading for very .plist I am at the entering in app I download all and parse every into dictionary and all of them put in cache dictionary ( key is plist name and value is plist parsed into dictionary). How to make dictionary ( NSDictionary or to use something else ) be thread safe for reading, inserting ?

Comment: You need some sort of lock/synchronization mechanism around the dictionary accesses, but note that this mechanism must also somehow assure that any key values you specify are invariant during the operation.  (If you use immutable strings for keys this is not an issue, but if you use keys of some other type you could have a problem.)

Comment: (But note that if you assure that the dictionary is "read only" in practice in every situation where simultaneous access is possible, you do not need to synchronize.)

Comment: (Although I see that NSDictionary is "generally considered to be thread-safe".  So presumably only the issue of mutable keys would be of concern.)

Answer (score 1):

You can used [`@synchronized`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW3) around each access to the shared object. I'd recommend building a wrapper object used for access so that you don't accidentally forget to synchronize in one place in the code.

```
@synchronized {
    NSString* settingValue = self.sharedDictionary[@"key"];
}
```

This is a language feature that gets translated to an exclusive mutex. If you need more control over how you sync, you should use one of the other synchronization primitives provided. Apple has a nice overview on that in their [Threading Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html).